# How do you $_POST 2 <select> values?

Tags: php, forms, session

I have tried this a few different ways including as a hidden value. 
I have 2 separate values I need assigned to $_SESSION variables, id and cust_name. Assigning them to the session in the foreach loop does not work because it breaks the echo output. The only way I found to get both values to the next url was by concatenating them to a delimiter but that appears to be causing me issues.
Is there another/better way to assign .$item['id'].":".$item['cust_name']. to individual session variable 'or' separate element in a $_POST value=  ?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6zsX.png

```
 <?php
     foreach ($result as $item){
                echo '<option value='.$item['id'].":".$item['cust_name'].'>';
                //echo '<option type="hidden" value='.$item['cust_name'].'>';
                echo ($item['cust_name'] .",". $item['cust_addr'] .",". $item['cust_phone'].","
. $item['id']."<br />\n");
                echo '</option>';
        }
```

Comment: why don't u use an underscore

Comment: @Nouphal.M I am not sure I follow you?

Comment: `$item['id']."_".$item['cust_name']` also if you pass only the id then u could query with id to get all the information

Comment: Still don't understand what you are trying to do... can you give some detailed info?

Comment: @Nouphal.M can you explain "query with id to get all "?  I can get id by it's self, I can use underscore as a delimiter, but getting 'all' in separate elements is my main goal or an array.

Comment: @charlee as demo'ed in the image, I am trying to get the <select> values for id and cust_name to my next url without using concatenated delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can push 2 variables to a second URL is by using javascript to populate a hidden variable on post, pulling information from a "data" attribute.

For example, you'd define the following as your option...

```
<option data-customerid="123" name="customername" value="Marty McFly">Marty McFly, 123 Fake Street, 555-555-5555</option>
```

Then, using javascript...

```js
$("#myform").submit( function(eventObj){
  $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="customerid" value="'+$('#myselect').find(':selected').attr('data-customerid');+'" /> ');               
  return true;
  });
```

`return true` at the end, then allows for the form to be posted in your normal way.

You will need to change `#myform` and `#myselect` in the above to the ID of your form, and the ID of your select element respectively.
If you want to send any more additional fields, repeat the line starting with `$(this), changing the ID accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your value tag like this, otherwise if cust_name contains space, it will be missed

```
echo '<option value="'.$item['id'].":".$item['cust_name'].'">';
              //    ^                                      ^ Add double quotes here
```

Comment: as demonstrated in the image paste, concatenating a delimiter isn't working out for me. Trying to find a different route.